# Running npm globally installed packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, emacs, npm

Can someone please explain how do node's globally installed behave. It is really confusing me. If I install a package (with executables) such as `http-server`globally I can run it with:

```
http-server
```

But if I do

```
node http-server
```

I get

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/path/to/current/dir/http-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:972:3
```

I suspect my `tern`package in `emacs` is trying to run it with `node` hence breaking. Why is this happening? Why can't node find the path to its own modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rahul@Rahul-Machine:~$ node blalal 
module.js:338
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/rahul/blalal'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
at startup (node.js:117:18)
at node.js:951:3
```

ooh same error

this is because i first command you are actually trying to access a global variable but in second you are some where in your file hierarchy and from there you are saying that you want to access that package so you are wrong if you want to execute that global package try

```
whereis http-server
```

then go to that directory and find the file package.json and then open it and find the "main" property and there you get a file name then type

```
  node index.js
```

your file will be executed

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways installing packages: `globally` and `locally`.

**Locally** installed package files end up in your local `node_modules` (in your project folder where you called `npm install some-package`).

**Globally** installed package files end up in your system so they are available in command line:

- if a globally installed package provides an executable then you can invoke it in command line directly with `some-package`(without `node`)
- if a globally installed package does not provide an executable, then you can use it in repl mode (`node`) with `var package = require('some-package')`; this will make it also available locally, inside your project, even if you don't have it installed locally.

Answer (score 3):

This started as a comment but got now a little longer.

The problem is not exactly `node` not finding global packages, `node` only searches for packages in the current location (like under under `node_modules`), and that is by design. Globally installed packages can be run from the command like because of the way `npm` installs them, and this is what makes global packages special in some way.

On Unix based systems, npm creates soft links to the main executables of globally installed packages, like `http-server` in a folder in the executable path. On my machine, this is `/usr/local/bin/`. This is why those commands can be invoked from the command line without specifying a full path.

On Windows, npm creates an executable batch file named for instance `http-server.cmd` under `%APPDATA%` (typically something like `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming`). The batch file contains instructions to run the target executable from the location where it's actually installed.

Comment: But why cant I run them with `node [package-name]`? Some packages (emacs packages) try to run these packages with the `node` prefix which is the confusing part

Comment: @Arijoon Probably because those packages expect to find their dependencies installed locally.

Comment: ok how can I make sure they find their dependencies globally? Since if I even install the same package locally it still won't run with `node [package-name]`

Answer (score 0):

When you install something globally you store a variable with a stored path linking to it as well as the execution program. While your operating system will know how to access it. Node will not. If you want to "node something.js" you much either be in the directory it is or adjust your path so that node knows how to get to the file. for instance **node "c:/jsapps/main/app.js"** or if you were in lets say the folder 'jsapps' you would type node **"main/app.js"** to execute the same file.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help you run the npm node module on the command line if you haven't installed it globally.
Either run it globally as they way you are doing.
Other option is to give full path of local package file. For example I want to run a package live-server which is installed as package locally in my current directory.

```
node ./node_modules/live-server/live-server --port=5000
```

Here(on my Mac) the live-server.js file is inside the live-server directory, Its optional to add .js and execute the command as below. Also port is optional argument for live-server

```
node ./node_modules/live-server/live-server.js --port=5000
```